# Using Boost (Spirit) with g++ (and later Eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, g++, boost-spirit

How can I configure g++ to use boost libraries? I Googled and tried many combinations but failed. I managed to get it working a few weeks ago ...

```
g++ test.cpp -o test -lboost
g++ test.cpp -o test -lboost_spirit
```

And afew with -I and -L flags ... but I always get

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am on Arch Linux. I will also like to know how to use Boost with Eclipse ... Looks like boost should have installed correctly?

```
[jiewmeng@JM-LAPTOP ~]$ ls /usr/include/boost/
accumulators                  move
algorithm                     mpi
aligned_storage.hpp           mpi.hpp
any.hpp                       mpl
archive                       msm
array.hpp                     multi_array
asio                          multi_array.hpp
asio.hpp                      multi_index
assert.hpp                    multi_index_container.hpp
assign                        multi_index_container_fwd.hpp
assign.hpp                    next_prior.hpp
bimap                         non_type.hpp
bimap.hpp                     noncopyable.hpp
bind                          nondet_random.hpp
bind.hpp                      none.hpp
blank.hpp                     none_t.hpp
blank_fwd.hpp                 numeric
call_traits.hpp               operators.hpp
cast.hpp                      optional
cerrno.hpp                    optional.hpp
checked_delete.hpp            parameter
chrono                        parameter.hpp
chrono.hpp                    pending
circular_buffer               phoenix
circular_buffer.hpp           phoenix.hpp
circular_buffer_fwd.hpp       pointee.hpp
compatibility                 pointer_cast.hpp
compressed_pair.hpp           pointer_to_other.hpp
concept                       polygon
concept_archetype.hpp         pool
concept_check                 preprocessor
concept_check.hpp             preprocessor.hpp
config                        program_options
config.hpp                    program_options.hpp
container                     progress.hpp
crc.hpp                       property_map
cregex.hpp                    property_tree
cstdint.hpp                   proto
cstdlib.hpp                   ptr_container
current_function.hpp          python
date_time                     python.hpp
date_time.hpp                 random
detail                        random.hpp
dynamic_bitset                range
dynamic_bitset.hpp            range.hpp
dynamic_bitset_fwd.hpp        ratio
enable_shared_from_this.hpp   ratio.hpp
exception                     rational.hpp
exception.hpp                 ref.hpp
exception_ptr.hpp             regex
filesystem                    regex.h
filesystem.hpp                regex.hpp
flyweight                     regex_fwd.hpp
flyweight.hpp                 scope_exit.hpp
foreach.hpp                   scoped_array.hpp
foreach_fwd.hpp               scoped_ptr.hpp
format                        serialization
format.hpp                    shared_array.hpp
function                      shared_container_iterator.hpp
function.hpp                  shared_ptr.hpp
function_equal.hpp            signal.hpp
function_output_iterator.hpp  signals
function_types                signals.hpp
functional                    signals2
functional.hpp                signals2.hpp
fusion                        smart_ptr
generator_iterator.hpp        smart_ptr.hpp
geometry                      spirit
geometry.hpp                  spirit.hpp
get_pointer.hpp               statechart
gil                           static_assert.hpp
graph                         strong_typedef.hpp
heap                          swap.hpp
icl                           system
implicit_cast.hpp             test
indirect_reference.hpp        thread
integer                       thread.hpp
integer.hpp                   throw_exception.hpp
integer_fwd.hpp               timer
integer_traits.hpp            timer.hpp
interprocess                  token_functions.hpp
intrusive                     token_iterator.hpp
intrusive_ptr.hpp             tokenizer.hpp
io                            tr1
io_fwd.hpp                    tuple
iostreams                     type.hpp
is_placeholder.hpp            type_traits
iterator                      type_traits.hpp
iterator.hpp                  typeof
iterator_adaptors.hpp         units
lambda                        unordered
last_value.hpp                unordered_map.hpp
lexical_cast.hpp              unordered_set.hpp
limits.hpp                    utility
local_function                utility.hpp
local_function.hpp            uuid
locale                        variant
locale.hpp                    variant.hpp
logic                         version.hpp
make_shared.hpp               visit_each.hpp
math                          wave
math_fwd.hpp                  wave.hpp
mem_fn.hpp                    weak_ptr.hpp
memory_order.hpp              xpressive
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no boost library and there is no boost_spirit library to link against. Spirit is a header only library, you only need to set the include path to your boost installation. On a Linux system it is usually installed under `/usr/include` which is the default, so you don't even need to do that.

To get boost on Arch Linux:

```
pacman -S boost boost-libs
```

Comment: @JiewMeng So, what is your problem?

Comment: I am still getting `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` on compile, as said in the qn

Comment: @JiewMeng As I said: there is no need to link with boost. You get that error, because there is no such library and you don't need to link with anything. Just drop the linker command from your compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

From [Header-Only Libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries)

> The only Boost libraries that must be built separately are:
>
> Boost.Filesystem
>
> Boost.IOStreams
>
> Boost.ProgramOptions
>
> Boost.Python
> (see the Boost.Python build documentation before building and
> installing it)
>
> Boost.Regex
>
> Boost.Serialization
>
> Boost.Signals
>
> Boost.Thread
>
> Boost.Wave
>
> A few libraries have optional separately-compiled binaries:
>
> Boost.DateTime has a binary component that is only needed if you're
> using its to_string/from_string or serialization features, or if
> you're targeting Visual C++ 6.x or Borland.
>
> Boost.Graph also has a binary component that is only needed if you
> intend to parse GraphViz files.
>
> Boost.Test can be used in “header-only” or “separately compiled” mode,
> although separate compilation is recommended for serious use.

You probably should set environment variable with path to includes needed.